# Embed an Image in a Mailview doesnt work anymore

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

After upgrade to 5.4 we have a problem with the Notifiy mailables, we embed the Application logo via

```
{{ $message->embed($path) }}
```

and it doesnt work anymore, i have a 5.3 copy where it works.. it looks like the $message variable is not injected automaticly anymore. we tried without the embedded image and the mailview is working.

Is there anything missing during our upgrade? i checked the upgradeguide twice.. we not using markdown.

Error:

```
Undefined variable: message (View: W:\project\resources\views\vendor\notifications\email.blade.php)
```

Codeexample:

```
User::find(1)->notify(
    new EmailCredentialsTest(User::find(1))
);
```

Comment: looks like a bug

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17629

Comment: Any update on this issue yet?